# Could not open Paradox.net

Tags: delphi, odbc, firedac, paradox

Trying Delphi 10.2 Tokyo with Paradox FireDAC ODBC on Windows 10 throws error  Could not open Paradox.net.  This link describes the problem: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221383(v=office.12).aspx

An Embarcadero FireDAC ODBC connection to Paradox table, by default will set ParadoxNetPath to System32 folder:

ODBCAdvanced=CollatingSequence=ASCII;DefaultDir=C:\DEV\TPDEMOS\DATA;DriverId=538;MaxBufferSize=2048;MaxScanRows=8;PageTimeout=600;ParadoxNetPath=C:\Windows\system32;ParadoxNetStyle=4.x;ParadoxUserName=admin;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UserCommitSync=Yes

There may be no write rights to that folder.  An easy solution is to try to set it to some place where user has read/write rights. Eg. Temp folder.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to ask a question and answer your own question, but I do not understand why you copied / pasted the same text into both. Further, you should never rely on external links - You can include them to support the content, but questions and answers should be self-contained right here on SO, without requiring the user to click somewhere else (which may not exist a year from now).

Comment: Well, `ODBCAdvanced` parameters are ODBC driver specific. Any of them can lead to something you don't like. And they are read from registry according to the chosen `ODBCDriver`. So, I don't think it's FireDAC who sets that path rather than driver installer. Besides, please, if you're main SW consultant at EMBT, try to consult this with Dmitry first. Thanks! ;)

Comment: I have to agree with @JerryDodge, its fine (and good practice) to answer your own question, but you should actually formulate the question and answer separately. Paradox is a long dead technology and should be used with a large amount of caution due to threading, multi-core, memory and permissions issues.

Comment: @Reallyethical, true, but in this case I would say it's FireDAC who's been trying to do its best by reading what driver specific info the ODBC driver installer wrote into registry. I mean, getting something you don't like to be setup might happen for any DBMS driver.

Comment: @Victoria you are of course correct but this technology has been depricated longer than most my staff have been adults. As such I would feel more than negligent to refrain from a warning in its use. Of course this could be inherited or a third party database but I will opine that it's use should be considered and approached with caution.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I have defined in the ODBC settings: ParadoxNetPath = 'PDOXUSRS.NET file path'.

This file must be in a folder where the current user has read and write permissions, so you do not have to run the "As Administrator" program.

If you use the BDE Administrator, you can change the path of the PDOXUSRS.NET file, which is usually at the root of the C: \ directory.

Another alternative would be to just run the program as Administrator, since this is the master of the system, the problem of this is that depending on where the application is executed, the client will not be allowed to do this operation.

Answer (score -2):

This link describes the problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221383(v=office.12).aspx

An Embarcadero FireDAC ODBC connection to Paradox table, by default will set ParadoxNetPath to System32 folder:

ODBCAdvanced=CollatingSequence=ASCII;DefaultDir=C:\DEV\TPDEMOS\DATA;DriverId=538;MaxBufferSize=2048;MaxScanRows=8;PageTimeout=600;ParadoxNetPath=C:\Windows\system32;ParadoxNetStyle=4.x;ParadoxUserName=admin;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UserCommitSync=Yes

There may be no write rights to that folder. An easy solution is to try to set it to some place where the user has read/write rights. Eg. Temp folder.